# Clearing buffer on fread() from fifo in C?

Tags: c, fread, fifo

I am reading continuous data (lines of text/strnigs) from a FIFO using C function `fread()`. Now I noticed that my process is growing bigger and bigger in ram. Can I somehow flush the buffer of the `fopen()`handle?
I can circumvent my process from growing if I do `fclose()` and subsequent `fopen()` after every line read, but is this really the solution?

```
int main() {
    unsigned char buffer[1];

    instream=fopen("/path/to/fifo", "r");
    if (instream!=NULL) {
        while (fread(&buffer, 1, 1, instream)==1) {
            // ...
        }
    }
    else {
        // error handling...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

This works, but seems ugly and error prone?

```
int main() {
    unsigned char buffer[1];

    instream=fopen("/path/to/fifo", "r");
    if (instream!=NULL) {
        while (fread(&buffer, 1, 1, instream)==1) {
            // ...

        if (buffer[0] == '\n') {
            fclose(instream);
            instream=fopen("/path/to/fifo", "r");
        }
    }
    else {
        // error handling...
    }

    return 0;
}
```

One additional question: is there a risk that my program reads faster than the output of the other program that writes into the fifo, and so `fread(...)` will be `0` and the `while`-loop will end?

Comment: 1. There's no reason for your program to be growing in memory unless you have a memory leak somewhere else. 2. read() (and therefore fread()) will block if there's no data available unless the file is specifically opened in non-blocking mode.

Comment: To add to Lee Daniel: use `valgrind` to check for your memleaks. There are also UI tooks like kcachegrind. To answer your other question: there is a fflush() method in C flushing the stream, but as mentioned fread is a _blocking_ call, so calling fflush will not do anything in this case as there is nothing to flush.

Comment: You seem to be right. If I remove my code that I replaced here with `// ...` it does indeed not grow. I thought I had figured that out, but it seems I was wrong.

Comment: Oh yes, I found the function that was causing the memory leak because of a missing `free(str)`. Thanks for the fast and concise answer :)